# How to uninstall VirtualBox in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, uninstall

Can anyone help me remove VirtualBox?

I am running 12.04.

Comment: open ubuntu software center an remove from there....

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*`

Answer (score 67):

To remove VirtualBox, I actually recommend running this command and *not* replacing `*` with anything (just run it exactly like so):

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-\*
```

If you want to remove global configuration files too (this does *not* remove your virtual machines), run exactly this instead:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-\*
```

[That method](https://askubuntu.com/a/190053/22949) is OK, but this way may be more thorough.

### Explanation

- You may have multiple VirtualBox-related packages installed. Assuming your machine no longer needs to be a VirtualBox host *or guest* machine, all these packages can go. For example, on the 11.10 box I'm using right now, there are 18 such packages available for installation (your machine might have some or even all of them, or other packages from your release or a PPA):

  ```
  virtualbox                      virtualbox-ose
  virtualbox-dbg                  virtualbox-ose-dbg
  virtualbox-dkms                 virtualbox-ose-dkms
  virtualbox-fuse                 virtualbox-ose-fuse
  virtualbox-guest-additions      virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms
  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso  virtualbox-ose-guest-utils
  virtualbox-guest-dkms           virtualbox-ose-guest-x11
  virtualbox-guest-utils          virtualbox-ose-qt
  virtualbox-guest-x11
  ```

  Some are probably already not installed, and some may be removed automatically as a consequence of removing others, but some would not.
- `apt-get` accepts `*` characters and treats them as part of a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). This is **in some ways** similar to the way a command-line shell processes `*`. When used in an `apt-get` command, `virtualbox-\*` (see below for why the `\`, which is not being used as regular expression syntax) actually matches *any package whose name contains `virtualbox`.*

  (Be careful with this as applied to packages with shorter names! For example, `wine\*` matches every package with `win`--not just `wine`--anywhere in its name.)

  So you don't have to manually expand `*`. It can stay, and it will catch the various related packages as described above, **as well as packages with explicit versions in their names** as [discussed there](https://askubuntu.com/a/190053/22949).
- However, *the shell itself*, which executes `apt-get` with the command-line arguments you specify, *also* accepts wildcards. Therefore, you should *escape* the wildcard (and one way to do that is with a `\` character before the `*`). Otherwise, if your expression matches a file or folder in that current location, the shell would give its name to `apt-get`, which would be wrong.

### What does purge do here?

`purge` removes global configuration files only. It does not remove virtual machines, so it's safe to use. However:

- It also doesn't remove most of the *settings* you might think it would. Remember, it removes *global* configuration files only. It does not remove any configuration files created by users that exist in their home directories and define how VirtualBox is configured *for them*.
- Configuration files rarely take up a lot of space. If your goal is to free space but you think you may want to use VirtualBox again, you might prefer not to use `purge`.

Also, please note: `apt-get --purge remove ...` is the same as `apt-get purge ...`.

Comment: Thank you, this is an exemplary answer! Very detailed written which makes it helpful for inexperienced users such as me :)

Comment: I tried this but I get this:    E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: @medoampir Make sure you're not running any other package management software at the same time. This includes the Software Center, Software Updater (Update Manager in older versions of Ubuntu), Synaptic, gdebi, or currently-running package management commands like `apt-get`, `aptitude`, and `dpkg`. Make sure no other currently logged-in users (if any) are running any such software. This may include non-administrators, since by default they may allow the Software Updater to install updates. If that still doesn't fix it, see [this question about the problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/15433/22949).

Comment: Wonderful explanation...!! @Eliah Kagan

Comment: Don't forget to remove per-user configuration afterwards (`rm -rf ~/.config/VirtualBox`)

Comment: Thank you! I've did not know more what to do.  Worked just fine!

Answer (score 11):

Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and issue the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-*
```

Replace **`*`** with the version of VirtualBox installed on your system (e.g. `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2`).

Alternatively, you can make use the auto-complete feature in the terminal by hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after typing `virtualbox`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Oracle VM VirtualBox and ubuntu 15.04

1. `sudo dpkg -l | grep virtualbox`

which shows something like this.

ii  virtualbox-4.2                        4.2.6-82870~Ubuntu~quantal                amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox

2. now from above command you can determine which version of virtual-box is installed on your machine.After this type these commands in your terminal,Just replace the 4.2 with your version of VirtualBox.

   `sudo  apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2 virtualbox-qt`

Answer (score 1):

For me nothing helped but this

```
$ sudo /opt/VirtualBox/uninstall.sh

vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
VirtualBox 5.1.22 r115126 has been removed successfully.

$ sudo rm -rf /opt/VirtualBox/
```

Answer (score 1):

### 16.04 and later

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox unity-scope-virtualbox ^virtualbox-
```

#### How to uninstall Oracle VirtualBox

If you installed VirtualBox from the Oracle website find your VirtualBox version as follows:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
aptitude search virtualbox\*
```

The latest version of VirtualBox that has `Oracle VM VirtualBox` on the same line with it is the package you have installed. If you have the latest version of Oracle VirtualBox installed, it is named `virtualbox-5.1`.

Verify that this version of Oracle VirtualBox is currently installed.

```
dpkg-query -s virtualbox-5.1
```

Uninstall Oracle VirtualBox using a command that looks like this:

```
sudo apt remove VirtualBox-5.1
```

If you have a different version of Oracle VirtualBox installed replace `VirtualBox-5.1` in the above command with your VirtualBox version.

Answer (score 0):

or use next command if you install vmbox from script:

```
sudo ./VirtualBox-4.1.4-74291-Linux_amd64.run remove
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to completely remove the package:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-\*
```