# VirtualBox Error

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox

My Ubuntu computer won't load VirtualBox.

The message I'm recieving is:
`Error:`
`Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.`
`The application will now terminate.`
`Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found.`
 
`Location: '/home/josh/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml', line 1 (0), column 1.`

`/build/buildd/virtualbox-4.1.18-dfsg/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[484] (nsresult VirtualBox::init())`

`Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)`
`Component: VirtualBox`
`Interface: IVirtualBox {c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66}`

My Computer is currently running Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Could you add some info? AKA, your computer type (eg. Toshiba Satellite A105, some specs, etc...) That would help.

Comment: It's a Dell inspiron comp with an AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5200+ × 2 with Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 64x and Linux Ubuntu 12.10 64x.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the VirtualBox.xml file?

Answer (score 3):

I have listed the files and found that there are 2 files . One named VirtualBox.xml and the other VirtualBox.xml-prev. I noticed that the first file`s size was 0 bytes and the second like 1243 bytes, anyway different than 0.

So I have opened the both files and I copied the content from VirtualBox.xml-prev to the first file, save and closed the file and worked.

In my laptop the files were located in `~/.VirtualBox`.

Comment: Short version, In your VM folder rename your *.xml-prev file to *.xml, for VirtualBox >= v4.0, rename the *.vbox-prev file to *.vbox.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the command `cp VirtualBox.xml-prev VirtualBox.xml`  solves for me. All previous boxes are found. No need to import VDIs etc. Very thoughtful that there exists a copy VirtualBox.xml-prev!

Answer (score 1):

Delete that file and everything will be okay.
Open your terminal and:

```
 rm /home/josh/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml
```

Comment: This may be true, but lacks a bit of information. Can you tell _why_ it is OK to delete that file and how this affects loading of the VM?

Comment: You will still need to reconfigure the virtual machine and relay the old disk drive to the new configuration once you delete this VirtualBox.xml.

Comment: It also deletes the vm I had! Anyway to recover it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can fixed it.

1. Uninstall whatever version of VirtualBox you currently have installed: [How to uninstall VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190004/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-in-12-04).
2. Delete the local hidden folder (`/.VirtualBox`, which contains an `.XML` file which is causing the error).
3. Install VirtualBox: [VirtualBox/Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation).