# Virtual box uninstall

Tags: virtualbox

I want to uninstall virtual box from my system. 
I run following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox* --purge
```

The result says it is uninstalled. But I could still launch the virtual box. Please let me know what needs to be done. Thanks

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall VirtualBox in 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/190004/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-in-12-04)

Comment: I tried all comments mentioned in the http://askubuntu.com/questions/190004/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-in-12-04 question. It says virtual box already uninstalled. Now when I try to install a new virtual box it says "breaks existing package 'virtualbox-5.0:i386'

Comment: What's the output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX dpkg -l virtualbox\*`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you installed VirtualBox from an installer file instead of from an apt repository--possibly in addition to installing from an apt repository (the latter you seem to have already removed, if it existed).  If the VirtualBox version is 2.2.2 or later, you can do this:

```
sudo /opt/VirtualBox/uninstall.sh
```

If it's an earlier version (2.2.1 or earlier), you need to find the installer file you downloaded (or re-download it) and run this from the same directory as that file:

```
./VirtualBox.run uninstall
```

If you can't find the appropriate installer file for a version 2.2.1 or earlier, then you need to remove all the files, manually.  To do this, perform the "manual installation" steps in reverse order, deleting files instead of creating/moving/copying them, deleting symlinks instead of creating them, removing edits to configuration files, etc.:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idp46457698198016

Comment: Thanks. I manually removed the files and reinstalled the updated virtual box and it worked.